# Sending request with text body in Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I am trying to send a body as `content-type: text/plain` but I am unable to retrieve it in my application.
I am doing something like this:

```
"days": [1, 2],
"time": {
    "to":8,
    "from":12
}
```

But when i try to access it in my controller it doesn't show anything.

```
   async testFunction(@Body() body, @Req() req) {
       console.log(req.body)
       console.log(body)
   }
```

But both logs are blank. How do i get text in body ??

Comment: May be in ur case it will be application/json content type

Comment: I dont think so.  Cause data i am sending in body is text/plain

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283713/how-do-i-pass-plain-text-as-my-request-body-using-nestjs)?

Comment: What does the server return?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a object you could simply use JSON instead of plain text:

```
POST replace_with_your_endpoint
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "days": [1, 2],
    "time": {
        "to":8,
        "from":12
    }
}
```

In one of your controllers:

```js
@Post()
postRequest(@Body() body: any) {
  console.log(body) // { days: [ 1, 2 ], time: { to: 8, from: 12 } }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to send it as an object but we have problems in postgres where it takes {} as the notation for array. which raises another error of malformed array

Comment: @new_programmer I would convert it before inserting. How did you solve the issue?